# XAML designer does not see C++/CX classes

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

Windows Store project in C++/CX. I've placed an instance of the custom C++ class on a XAML page. I've marked it with a namespace. The project builds. Yet the design surface does not display the control, claims it's not present in the assembly. The XAML goes like this:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="MyApp.Foo"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400" Loaded="OnLoaded">

...
<local:MyControl x:Name="Bar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

The `MyControl` class is declared in code like this:

```
[Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
public ref class MyControl sealed : Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Canvas
{
 ...
};
```

It has a public default contructor with no parameters. What's wrong here, please?

Comment: Is MyControl declared just in code, or does it have a XAML definition as well?  It's possible it will only show in the designer if it is a xaml control (instead of just a derived class).

Comment: Just in code. But there's another one, that's a user control (with XAML, derived from UserControl), and it has trouble on the design surface, too.